# When merging topics, show deleted question/diff in revision history

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, diff, merged-questions

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891510/display-label-character-by-character-using-javascript) was merged with an earlier question, to which I'd posted an answer.  I'd been drifting to and from my computer from time to time during the day and noticed the page was still open so I refreshed it to see there were any updates, only to find a "page not found" message.  [This problem has been raised before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891510/display-label-character-by-character-using-javascript) so I don't really want to get into that.

I found the other post by searching for keywords I remembered in the question, wasn't difficult.  But I noticed that the new post was slightly different - the code sample in the question was altered, which made a couple of the answers (including mine) posted in the earlier question sort of irrelevant.  Although the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2891510/revisions) shows a merge took place, there was no link to the revision history in the question, no indication that the post had been edited or changed.  So I'd like to make the following suggestions:

- Show a "merged" message with a link where you would usually find the edited message:

> merged 8 hours ago
> Bill the Lizard ♦
> 53.6k •15 •95 •215

- Perform a diff between the two and show in the revision history.

Comment: Questions that have been merged away now redirect to the target question for users who aren't logged in (at least), and include a post notice pointing to the target question. I believe there are also entries shown in the revision history and/or the post timeline for both posts, though someone else will have to confirm that... That said, I assume those wouldn't be applied retroactively to earlier merges from before those features were added.